# How to hide xml file data in android app?

Tags: android, xml

I have android application, all the data comes from XML file which I load to my app when the the app is starting.
How can I prevent from the XML data to be copied? 
should I encrypt the file or is there an easier way?

Comment: how do you mean, it is copied?

Comment: There is no 100% solution possible. Whatever you do, when the app can read the file an attacker can do as well (by just mimicking the app).

Comment: Protext XML files? Ha ha...You could redesign your app to include this data programmatically at runtime and that code you can obfuscate with things like ProGuard.....but.....like the other's have said.

Comment: I mean if someone take that xml file he can easily create an app with it because that data is the main thing...
its not need to be 100% secured, its not something that everyone are interested of...

Comment: If you compile the data into the app as Java strings, you can use [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) (the paid version of ProGuard) to obfuscate the string literals. As @Henry wrote, it's never going to be 100% secure, but it would raise the bar.

Comment: ok. so if I will build a class inside the app that will store all the data it is good for hiding the data?
and btw, what about pictures I have in my app, are they protected in the app or is it possible to copy it from somewhere in the device?

Answer (score 0):

encrypt the xml file with a key and add to your app. Then decrypt it in your app and then parse as necessary.

As Barend mentioned a quick way to hide it would be to make a string

string strXML=".....